# add days to a date column and then check if it's between two dates SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a sql query to find the data from a employee table.
Startdate is present in employee table.
I need to add 90 days in startdate and then I need to check if the startdate lies in the current month or not.

I did try below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `employees` 
WHERE DATE_ADD(str_to_date(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y'),INTERVAL 90 DAY) BETWEEN '09/01/2016' AND '09/30/2016'
```

but its not giving me the expected results.(I do have data which should show up if the query is correct.)

Hi i did change the query and ran, please see the result. I am getting results of next month too :(

This is the query 
SELECT id,startdate from employees WHERE str_to_date(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 90 day) -- start of this month - 90 days and DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 90 day)

[Query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOjyb.jpg)

Comment: tag DBMS you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Rephrased my query...

Where the event was within the dates 90 days before the start and end of this month

```
WHERE str_to_date(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between 
    DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 90 day)  -- start of this month - 90 days
    and DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 90 day) -- End of this month - 90 days
```

or, for three months

```
WHERE str_to_date(startdate, '%m/%d/%Y') between 
    DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 3 month)  -- start of this month - 3 months
    and DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 month) -- End of this month - 3 months
```

Comment: Thank you :) , i should have thought in this way.

Comment: i did change the query and ran. I am getting results of next month too :(

Comment: @Anant Are you sure you want 90 days? It's not the same as 3 months. For example, 1st Sep - 90 days is 3rd June, 30th Sep - 90 days is 2nd July, which means 1st and 2nd of July will appear.

Comment: Ya, that's what is needed. 
can we use Y-m-t to check the end of the month